# install hadoop 3.1.2 WARNING: HADOOP_PREFIX has been replaced by HADOOP_HOME. Using value of HADOOP_PREFIX

Tags: hadoop, installation

i am new to hadoop and i want to install the latest verison 3.1.2 and i'm following this tutoriel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6oit3rCsZo
which is based on this tutoriel: https://ricma.co/install-apache-hadoop-27-on-buntu-1604.html 
i already have java 8 installed , so i skip the java installation on the tuto and when i get to format nodename part (hdfs namenode -format i get : No command 'hdfs' found, did you mean:
 Command 'hfs' from package 'hfsutils-tcltk' (universe)
 Command 'hdfls' from package 'hdf4-tools' (universe)
hdfs: command not found
i tried  (bin/hdfs namenode -format) and it worked with warning (WARNING: HADOOP_PREFIX has been replaced by HADOOP_HOME. Using value of HADOOP_PREFIX.
WARNING: log4j.properties is not found. HADOOP_CONF_DIR may be incomplete.
) but next i try (bin/start-dfs.sh) or(start-dfs.sh) i get (-su: bin/start-dfs.sh: No such file or directory) 
i think the problem is with the bashrc file or /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh file can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

i was in your position with these tutorial youtube and problem, so the main problem is in hadoop version, tutorial use hadoop 2.7.* but we installed 3.1.* 
so if see file usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh , Youtube Version and 3.1.2 are diffrent value

Solution : 
use hadoop version 2.7.* if you follow that youtube tutorial 
yo can install 2.7.7 version, here : 
https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.7/hadoop-2.7.7.tar.gz